# ¿Imprimir nombre de session (si existe) en etiqueta <h1> ? PHP

Tags: php

**Problema**:

Quiero imprimir el nombre del usuario, para saludarlo, si es que ha iniciado sesión en la pagina. Si no ha iniciado sesión entonces quiero que el titulo sea el titulo por defecto de la página.

**Código de log in:**

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

    unset($_SESSION['error']);

    if(!isset($_POST['usuario']) || !isset($_POST['contrasenia'])) {

    }else{

    $usuario     = $_POST["usuario"];
    $contrasenia = md5($_POST["contrasenia"]);

        if ($resultado = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from Usuarios where usuario='" . $usuario . "' and contrasenia='" . $contrasenia . "'")) {

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

                if ($row['contrasenia'] == $contrasenia && $row['usuario'] == $usuario) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                    header("Location: index.php");
                }
            } else {
                unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
                $_SESSION["error"] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta";   
            }  
        }
    }
?>
```

Como ven, cuando hago el LogIn y el usuario y contraseña están bien, me redirige al index.php !!! Hasta acá bien, pero en el index.php, en el titulo o etiqueta , si la sesión NO ESTÁ iniciada me sale esto:

> Notice: Undefined index: usuario in
>   /var/www/html/PaginaFinal/php/index.php on line 24

Y si está iniciada me sale solamente el nombre del usuario logueado, pero no el "Bienvenido + $nombreUsuario" ...

**Código del index.php:**

```
   <?php
        session_start();
   ?>
```

---- Sigue el HTML -------

Y viene el  :

```
<h1 id="titulo"> <?php echo "Bienvenido ".isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) ? $_SESSION["usuario"] : "TIENDA X MAYOR";?></h1>
```

Osea, explico de nuevo. Lo que quiero hacer es que si el usuario está logueado el H1 diga "Bienvenido + el nombre del usuario que se logueo" .... si no está logueado quiero que diga "Tienda X Mayor"

Comment: Prueba así: `$usuario=!(empty($_SESSION["usuario"])) ? $_SESSION["usuario"] : "Tienda al Por Mayor";`  y luego: `<h1 id="titulo"> <?php echo "Bienvenido ".$usuario;?></h1>`

Comment: Gracias hermano :) Sirvió

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes determinar el estado de la sesión usando bien un ternario:

```
$usuario=!(empty($_SESSION["usuario"])) ? $_SESSION["usuario"] : "Tienda al Por Mayor";
```

Y luego lo agregas a tu html.

A mi me gusta escribir el código sin mezcla, usando variables:

```
<?php
  $usuario = $_SESSION["usuario"];
  $html="<h1 id=\"titulo\">Bienvenido $usuario</h1>";
  echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

He ejecutado un código similar al tuyo y me funciona:

login.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["usuario"] = "Usuario2";
  header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<h1 id="titulo"> <?php echo "Bienvenido ".isset($_SESSION["usuario"]) ? 
$_SESSION["usuario"] : "TIENDA X MAYOR";?></h1>
```

Por el error que te da, `$usuario` no tiene nada, y entonces se asigna undefined. Haz un `var_dump($usuario);` y comenta provisionalmente el redirect de esta forma `header("Location: index.php");` y mira a ver si te da algún valor o no.

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo poniéndolo en in input sin bordes, y ya después de eso le das estilo con css

```html
<?php

    session_start();

    if($_SESSION["usuario"] == TRUE) {

    if (isset($_SESSION["usuario"])) {
        //asignar a variable
    $usernameSesion = $_SESSION["usuario"];
        //asegurar que no tenga "", <, > o &
    $username = htmlspecialchars($usernameSesion);}}


?>

<input type="text" style="width: 50%; border: none;" <?php if( $username <> "") { ?> value="Bienvenido  <?php echo $username; ?>  a TIENDA X MAYOR" <?php }else{ ?> value="Bienvenido a TIENDA X MAYOR" <?php } ?>>
```